# Is it possible to detemine element location in WebView in JavaFX?

Tags: java, dom, webview, webkit, javafx

Suppose I have loaded some HTML into `WebView`. And suppose this HTML contains some `DIV` element. Can I detemine geometric location of this DIV element after rendering? So that I can track if mouse point is over it or not.

**UPDATE**

Yes, the question is about external web pages of not mine. I want to make some thorough exploration of a page with Java.

I have read that `WebView` is implemented with `WebKit`. Is it possible to access any `WebKit` internals from Java then?

Also. Is it possible to download, say, jquery, in addition to already loaded page and call `offset()` function for it?

Comment: [This discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446510/how-do-i-include-jquery-in-javafx-webview) has some solutions for executing jquery on an arbitrary page in webview.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way (that I know of) to get the screen coordinates of a div.

However, you can call back to your Java code from Javascript. So you could write a small amount of Javascript that detects when the mouse enters and exits the div, and call some Java code that updates a BooleanProperty, for example. See "Calling back to Java from Javascript" in the [WebEngine API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html).

UPDATE: example

UPDATE: simplified code

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HTMLMouseOverTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        final BooleanProperty mouseOver = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> observable,
                    State oldValue, State newValue) {
                if (newValue == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    // Here's how to add the Javascript if you don't have
                    // direct access to the HTML:
//                    final Document doc = engine.getDocument();
//                    Element div = doc.getElementById("important-div");
//                    div.setAttribute("onmouseover", "mouseOverProperty.set(true)");
//                    div.setAttribute("onmouseout", "mouseOverProperty.set(false)");
                    final JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
                    window.setMember("mouseOverProperty", mouseOver);                    
                }
            }
        });
        engine.loadContent("<html><body style='font-family:sans-serif';><h2>Hello World</h2>"+
            "<div id='important-div' onmouseover='mouseOverProperty.set(true)'"+
                "onmouseout='mouseOverProperty.set(false)' style='background: #ffd; padding:40px;'>"+ 
            "Move mouse here</div>"+
            "<h3>Thanks and good night</h3></body></html>");

        root.setCenter(webView);
        final Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(mouseOver).then("Mouse in position").otherwise("Mouse out of area"));
        root.setBottom(label);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you don't have control over the HTML that's being loaded (it's coming from an external site, for example), you can manipulate the DOM and insert the required Javascript when the page is loaded. This starts to get a bit messy, but it will work. The same docs for WebEngine show how to get access to the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

The rendering is happening on the client side. The only way to have this information on the server is by writing JS code to gather this data and then send them up to server.

No way to do it only via server side code

Comment: This is a JavaFX question: everything is client side.

Comment: There might not be a physical Web Server involved, but the client-server architecture is still there.

Comment: Not necessarily. This could be a regular desktop application, the HTML loaded into the WebView could be a static resource in the application jar file, for example. At any rate, I think the OP is looking to track a mouse hover for the DIV element in the JavaFX code, which is definitely not on the server.