# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while executing webemgine.executescript

Tags: java, exception, webview, javafx, invocationtargetexception

I am using **JavaFX** to highlight text in a webview. But when I run my code; following exceptions occurs.Can someone give me a solution please.

Thanks in advance.
Edit: I've added the full stack of errors below. As I was suggested.

```
@FXML
private void _do_highlight(WebEngine engine, String _text) {
  engine.executeScript("$('body').removeHighlight().highlight('" + _text + "')");
}    
@FXML
private void hcone(MouseEvent event) {
    str = one.getText();  // 'one' is a Textfield ... 
    if (submited == true) {    
        WebEngine engine = webview.getEngine();  
        engine.loadContent("<body><div id='content'>Hello asdfasdfasdf</div></body>");
        _do_highlight(engine, str); // Each time str is found in webview, it must be highlighted
    }
}
```

This error Occurs

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3437)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$7900(Scene.java:3365)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3733)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
at     com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at              com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/584634336.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
... 30 more
Caused by: netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
at com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:128)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1426)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:948)
at bioassignment.StringOccurenceController._a_highlight(StringOccurenceController.java:83)
at bioassignment.StringOccurenceController.hcone(StringOccurenceController.java:96)
... 40 more
```

Comment: It seems `_do_highlight()` shouldn't have the `@FXML` annotation, if it is a private method you call from your controller. Also, you should show the full stack of the exception, so we can find where is the error.

Comment: I've tried after removing @FXML .. Result remains the same.. And full stack of exceptions are given now..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception

> netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

it seems you are not loading jQuery properly.

If you have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446510/how-do-i-include-jquery-in-javafx-webview), you have to load jQuery first, and then perform your script.

This is working for me without exceptions (though the content has nothing highlighted and the script doesn't work...):

```
@FXML private WebView webView;

@FXML private TextField one;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
}    

@FXML
private void hcone(ActionEvent event){
    String str = one.getText();
    if(!str.isEmpty()){
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.loadContent("<body><div id='content'>Hello asdfasdfasdf</div></body>");
        engine.documentProperty().addListener(
            (prop, oldDoc, newDoc) -> _do_highlight(engine, str));
    }
}

private void _do_highlight(WebEngine engine, String _text) {
    executejQuery(engine,"$(\"body\").removeHighlight().highlight('" + _text + "');");
}
```

where `executejQuery()` is the method refered in that answer that checks if the document loaded in a webEngine has a version of jQuery corresponding to the minimum required version loaded, and, if not, then loads jQuery into the document from the default jQuery location.

Note that I've added a listener, as the function requires the document to be loaded into the WebView before executing the script to inject jQuery.